# a href to url grabbing a select from drop down

Tags: javascript, html

what i'm trying to do is to get the value selected from a select list and use it in a href call, here is an example:

```
 $query="SELECT distinct(loca_cod) as id, localidad as nombre FROM $tabla WHERE     parti_cod='$stateId' order by nombre asc";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<div class="styled-select">
<select name="city">
<option>Seleccione Localidad</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value = "<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['nombre']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
</div>
<br />
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="step2.php?uch=HERE GOES THE VALUE SELECTED FROM USER class="boton_res">Continue</a></td>
</tr>
```

Any tip on how to proceed?
Thanks!

Comment: Why have you got php in your html for a JavaScript (client-side) question? Could you show the rendered ('view source') html, as seen by your browser?

Comment: Because i'm retrieving a list of cities coming from a database, i want to send the city using the href call, not a form, i will give the user 2 options, that's why i want to use the href.

Answer (score 0):

Try with do while instead

```
<option>Seleccione Localidad</option>
<? do {?>
<option value = "<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['nombre']?></option>
<? } while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) ; ?>
</select>
</div>
<br />
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="step2.php?uch=HERE GOES THE VALUE SELECTED FROM USER class="boton_res">Continue</a></td>
</tr>
```